# older vervion of ipa file is much more stable then upgraded one

Tags: ipa

If an app that is free and upgraded to a newer version. I have the ipa of the older version many in my group would like to revert back to older version. Question is how can an ipa be resign so that they can all use it. 
What do i need to do. The updated version has many issues and unstable we fly drones for hobbies, many of us lost them because the new upgraded version app had bugs in it they came up with another update know one trust it, so im asking how can i help to get my ipa file so that guys can use it hope you guys understand
thanks

Comment: Please add punctuation and capitalization to your question. This is hardly readable...

Comment: ok will do better next time